# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in jQuery $.each and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the value/s of a property called quantity that is contained in a JSON array called items but I keep on getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at the start of the jQuery.each() loop. Could someone please explain where I am going wrong. Many thanks in advance!

JSON -

```
{"items":[    
    {"id":"12345", "quantity":"2",},    
    {"id":"54321", "quantity":"3",}  

]}
```

AJAX -

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
      url: "https://example.com/cart/change.json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      quantity : $(this).val()
  },
//JSON response
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //formatted JSON data
      $('#subtotal').html(data.items_subtotal_price); //set subtotal from JSON
      console.log($(self).attr('id')); //item id of clicked input

      $.each(data.items.quantity, function(key,val){
      console.log(key + '-' + val)
          }

)}
});
});
```

Comment: `data.items` is an array.  `data.items.quantity` is not a valid accessor.  You have to loop over the items

Comment: I couldnt see where I was going wrong, thanks Taplar!

Comment: @BobtheBuilder like Taplar said quantity is not  a valid accessor check William Gunawan answer to access your quntity item

Comment: Yes Williams solution is spot on thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong in here.

```
      $.each(data.items.quantity, function(key,val){
  console.log(key + '-' + val)
      });
```

Above code you are trying to point data.items.quantity which mean data.items is a Array not Object. Access the quantity inside each.

it should be like this

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, item){
  console.log(item.quantity);
});
```